# Disable administrative shares in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows

What will happen if I disable the administrative shares in Windows 7? It will harm my computer?

Answer (score 2):

Disabling Administrative Shares is not recommended my Microsoft. You can read more about it [here](http://support2.microsoft.com/Default.aspx?id=842715&wa=wsignin1.0)

In short , it might affect your computer locally:

- You may find unknown processes that start from the Startup folder or from the Run key in the registry.
- Antivirus software may detect viruses, worms, Trojans or backdoors.
- Or the FTP root on a Web server may be filled with unknown files.

It can also cause some shares to become inaccessible on the affected computer.

When you try to access or view the affected computer remotely by using a UNC path, a mapped drive, the net use command, the net view command, or by browsing the network in Network Neighborhood or My Network Places, you may receive an error message that is similar to one of the following:

- The server is not configured for transactions.
- System error 53 has occurred.
- The network path was not found.
  Domain_Name is not accessible.

Comment: Also found an answer here though I can't recommend it http://superuser.com/questions/249701/is-it-ok-to-disable-the-administrative-shares-on-windows-7?rq=1 .                                   It hasn't been upvoted & it goes against what Microsoft themselves have recommended

Answer (score 0):

And here's how to actually disable those gigantic security holes:

Add a (DWORD, 32-bit) Value to the `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Parameters` Key, `AutoShareWks`, and ensure it has a value of `0`:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Services\LanmanServer\Parameters]
"AutoShareWks"=dword:00000000
```